# Finding the closest point on a surface to the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, vectors, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find the point on this surface $f(x,y)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{xy}$ where $x,y>0$ that is closest to the origin.

I know intuitively that this would be a normal vector , $a=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ ,from the surface that passes through the origin. So by working out $\nabla f(x,y)$, I should be able to write an equation: 
$$\displaystyle \lambda\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=a$$

This is:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\
y_0\\
z_0
\end{bmatrix}
=\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1}{x_0^2y_0}\\
\frac{-1}{x_0y_0^2}\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But this seems incredibly fiddly and I honestly need to know if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AM-GM is an elegant way to solve this, but I don’t think that solving it via computing the normal to the surface is at all “fiddly.”

Let $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z$. You’re looking for a point on the surface at which the normal is parallel to the vector from the origin to the point. In $\mathbb R^3$ this can be expressed as $(x,y,z)\times\nabla F(x,y,z)=0$. This is equivalent to your Lagrange multiplier formulation, but avoids introducing an additional variable. We compute $$(x,y,z)\times\nabla f(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)\times\left(-\frac1{x^2y},-\frac1{xy^2},-1\right) = \left(\frac z{xy^2}-y,x-\frac z{x^2y},\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{y^2}\right)=0.$$ From the last component and the fact that $x$ and $y$ are both positive, we have $x=y$, and from the equation of the surface, $z=\frac1{xy}$. Making these substitutions reduces this system of equations to the single equation $x^6=1.$

Answer (score 2):

AM-GM:

$x,y >0;$

$d^2=z^2+x^2+y^2=$

$(1/xy)^2+ x^2+y^2 \ge 3(1)^{1/3}=3$.

Attained for $x^2=y^2=(1/xy)^2$, for $x=y=1$.